# Map is not smoothly rotating in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Hi I am working with Maps in iPhone. Iam rotating map view with directions. Map is rotating, but not moving smoothly.

I am using below code for rotating the map. can any one tell me any suggestions for rotating map view smoothly?

```
float oldRad =  -manager.heading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
float newRad =  -newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0f;
CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
theAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:oldRad];
theAnimation.toValue=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:newRad];
theAnimation.duration = 0.5f;
[mapView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad)];
CGPoint anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[[mapView annotations] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) 
 {
     MKAnnotationView * view = [mapView viewForAnnotation:obj];

     [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad)];
     [view setCenterOffset:CGPointApplyAffineTransform(anchorPoint, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(newRad))];

 }];
```

Comment: I don't see any code that actually attaches `theAnimation` to `mapView`.  Did you leave out a call to `[mapView.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"transform"]`?

Comment: Hi thank you very much. i added your line of code below this line theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"]; Mapview rotating smoothly, but when rotating to 360degrees, it is rotating fastly to current position, can u tell me any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 5.0 and newer, you can use

```
[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading animated:YES];
```

Check [MKMapView's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html), particularly the section **Tracking the User Location** for more information on this.

However, if you still want to support older versions of iOS, you will have to go through all the pain of working out these glitches and bugs. I've done it myself (before iOS 5 was out), and believe me, you are better off with dropping support of iOS 4.